# ImportError : No module named _sqlite3 on GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sqlite

While trying to start local Google App Engine (v1.3.8) Server on my Fedora 14 with Python 2.5 (installed from source) I get the importerror

```
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
```

I have the following package installed - sqlite, sqlite-devel, python2.5, python2.7. I did some Google and it looks like this error comes when there is no C binding for sqlite. However, since I have both the sqlite and sqlite-devel installed C bindings should be present. I get this same error when I do

```
import sqlite3
```

on Python console. What possibly can I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install `sqlite-devel` and rebuild Python.

Answer (score 3):

This works equally on Ubuntu 10.10 using

> $ sudo aptitude install **sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev**

and rebuilding Python.